# PHP SOAP Client. HTTPS cannot connect

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Cannot for the life of my to get this SOAP client working. Works fine on My friends box and I've compared the php.ini's and cannot see anything relating to SOAP settings. I'm running latest PHP and UBuntu 12.10.

Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl";
$options["connection_timeout"] = 1000;
$options["location"] = $url;
$options['trace'] = 1;


try {
$client = new SoapClient("orange.xml",$options);

print_r($client->__getFunctions());



$client->peekMessages(
    'user',
    'pass',
    10
);

var_dump($client);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
    echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
    echo "RESPONSE HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastResponseHeaders() . "\n";
    echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
    echo "Exception: \n" . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo "Trace: \n" . $e->getTraceAsString() . "\n";
}
```

I had to save the WSDL as a file otherwise I receive a different error!

Here is the code running:

```
Array
(
    [0] => int sendMessage(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer)
    [1] => ArrayOf_xsd_string getDeliveryReports(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $countryCode)
    [2] => ArrayOf_xsd_string readMessages(string $username, string $password, int $count, string $deviceMsisdn, string $countryCode)
    [3] => boolean flushMessages(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $countryCode)
    [4] => ArrayOf_xsd_string waitForMessage(string $username, string $password, int $timeout, string $deviceMSISDN, int $msgref, string $countryCode)
    [5] => int sendMessageWithValidityPeriod(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer, string $binarySmsDcs, string $validityDaysHoursMins)
    [6] => int sendBinarySmsMessage(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer, string $binarySmsDcs)
    [7] => ArrayOf_xsd_string sendAndWait(string $username, string $password, int $timeout, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer)
    [8] => ArrayOf_xsd_string sendBinarySmsAndWait(string $username, string $password, int $timeout, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer, string $binarySmsDcs)
    [9] => ArrayOf_xsd_string peekMessages(string $username, string $password, int $count, string $deviceMsisdn, string $countryCode)
    [10] => ArrayOf_xsd_string getDeliveryReportsFromDate(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $countryCode, string $fromDate)
)
REQUEST:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.otel.telematics.orange.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:peekMessages><username xsi:type="xsd:string">username</username><password xsi:type="xsd:string">password</password><count xsi:type="xsd:int">10</count><deviceMsisdn xsi:nil="true"/><countryCode xsi:nil="true"/></ns1:peekMessages></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

REQUEST HEADERS:

RESPONSE HEADERS:

RESPONSE:

EXCEPTION: 
Could not connect to host
Trace: 
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://m2mconn...', '', 1, 0)
#1 /var/www/soap-app.com/Zend/public/soap.php(34): SoapClient->__call('peekMessages', Array)
#2 /var/www/soap-app.com/Zend/public/soap.php(34): SoapClient->peekMessages('username', 'password', 10)
#3 {main}
```

My username & password are correct. I believe it has something to do with SSL. Here  are my SOAP and SSL php.ini settings:

```
soap
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled 

Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls

curl    SSL     Yes 

openssl
OpenSSL support             enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version      OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012 
SSL Version                 OpenSSL/1.0.1c
```

Any help would be great. Pulling my hair out!

More details:

Running:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/Message‌​ServiceByCountry?wsdl');
```

Results in:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto.
```

Edit:

Seems these bug tickets are relevant:
    https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52106

However I'm using latest PHP version, and I need to as I am using Zend Framework 2.

Comment: (1) is `allow_url_fopen=1`? (2) Can you `file_get_contents('https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl');`?

Comment: *Could not connect to host* <- connection problem. Check your network settings. And don't pull all your hair out ;)

Comment: Nothing wrong with my network connection as I can browse to the site via browser. allow_url_fopen is 1.

Comment: file_get_contents returns Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all this was because of my network settings. I was using a router with the open source firmware DD-WRT installed on it to extend my wireless network. When I took that router out of the network the connection succeeds. Took me a week to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl

Does not appear to load, same with just http://

If you say you can get to it then this shouldn't be a problem. However, if you need more help, then I suggest you make it so that we can access the URL. Then we can give it the proper testing and better solutions.

Comment: can you connect? I'm having no luck solving this

Comment: Appears your link still does not work. Make certain you don't have any firewalls blocking us from seeing it for now.

Comment: What? It works on about 4 different devices I've tried it on. It is not my server. It's orange. As in Orange the telecommunications network!